# Два родителя с элементами в один родитель

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно пересобрать два блока с элементами в один с последовательным отображением элементов друг за другом? Например, у нас есть такая верстка

```html
<div class="grid-6">
  <div class="el">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="el">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="el">
    3
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-6">
  <div class="el">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="el">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="el">
    6
  </div>
</div>
```

Нужно получить следующий код

```html
<div class="grid-6">
  <div class="el">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="el">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="el">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="el">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="el">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="el">
    6
  </div>
</div>
```

Как этого можно добиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот мой вариант, в отличие от уже предложенных он не использует никакие сторонние библиотеки вроде жуквери и делает разметку, как попросил автор

```js
    var grids = select(document, '.grid-6');
    var arr = grids.map(el => select(el, '.el'));
    arr[0].forEach((el, i) => {
        grids[0].appendChild(el);
        grids[0].appendChild(arr[1][i]);
    });
    grids[1].remove();

    function select(el, sel) {
        return [].slice.call(el.querySelectorAll(sel))
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid-6">
    <div class="el">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="el">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="el">
        3
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-6">
    <div class="el">
        4
    </div>
    <div class="el">
        5
    </div>
    <div class="el">
        6
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов:

```js
var parents = $(".grid-6");
parents.eq(1).appendTo(parents.eq(0));
parents.eq(1).replaceWith(parents.eq(1).contents());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-6">
  <div class="el">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="el">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="el">
    3
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-6">
  <div class="el">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="el">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="el">
    6
  </div>
</div>
```